# Ionic / AngularJS key not accessible in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to access the `{{key}}` from an `ng-repeat` from a controller using **Ionic 1**. The `{{key}}` that is generated as text is different from the `{{key}}` I am receiving at the controller, not sure why this is.

What I want to do is find the div id which should be dynamically generated using the `id = "historyHeader_{{key}}"` and need to receive it using `ng-click="loadInlineHistory({{key}})"`

**Controller:**

```
$scope.loadInlineHistory = function (dateLoaded) {
    var textS = $("#historyHeader_"+dateLoaded).text();
}
```

**View**

```
<ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in history  | groupBy: 'date'"" style="background:#fff;padding:0.4em">

        <div class="item item-divider">
            <span style="min-height: 100%" id="historyHeader_{{key}}"> {{key}}</span>
        </div>      

        <div style="width: 100%">

            <div class="row" ng-repeat="hist in value">
                <div ng-click="testRepeatx()">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-50"  align="left">3 laterals  </div>
                        <div class="col col-50" align="left" style="color:#999">{{hist.reps}} calories</div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="row" >
                <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="loadInlineHistory({{key}})"> <i class="ion-plus"></i></button>
            </div>      

        </div>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: key value is accessible for objects. can you show us the `history` object?

Comment: And if `{{key}}` is available in the view then you should easily access it just by using `loadInlineHistory(key)` in ng-click

Comment: @JunaidSalaat yes that was the problem, I was using {{key }} and for some reason it was giving me a different number, removing those helped, thanks!

Comment: Can I submit an answer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the curly brackets from the `ng-click` function call.

```
<div class="row" >
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced"
      ng-click="loadInlineHistory(key)"> <i class="ion-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```